# How to play Borderlands PvP?

Tags: borderlands

I could play online with 2 or 3 people only in cooperative mode until now. How to play versus?

Does this game have at least a fast paced action mode? It seems very slow...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The PvP for Borderlands is a [battle in the Arenas](http://borderlands.wikia.com/wiki/Arena), or just duel another player anywhere in the game.

To start a Duel, you can simply target another player and melee attack them (`V`). If they have duels turned on, it'll start it up.

Otherwise you can fight in the Arena. The Arena fight is max 4 players.